# Are there use cases for private public-virtual methods?

Tags: c++11, visibility

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "A"; };
};

struct B : public A
{
private:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "B"; }
};

int main()
{
    A *p = new B;
    p->foo();      // prints B

//    B b;
//    b.foo();     // error: foo is private
    return 0;
}

// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
```

So we can call `B.foo()` polymorphically, but not directly. Are there any use cases, when someone would want to use this functionality?

Answer (score 5):

It sort of depends on the design of the base class. Suppose you have a base class

```
class Stream {
public:
  virtual bool canSeek() = 0;
  virtual void seek(int offset) = 0;
};
```

Note: this example comes from the .NET world, where the base class library `Stream` class really does have such a virtual `CanSeek` property. I do not wish to discuss whether this is good design, as I can see valid arguments for both sides. It suffices that such base classes exist in reality.

Now, a derived class may specify that

```
class SpecificStream final : Stream {
private:
  virtual bool canSeek() { return false; }
  virtual void seek(int offset) { throw "no seek for you"; }
}
```

In this derived class, the fact that `seek` is implemented at all is because it is technically required. However, any code that deals with this `SpecificStream` already knows that the `seek` function is utterly useless with this class and should not be called. When coding against the base `Stream` class, it may make sense to check `canSeek()`'s result and call `seek` only if the result was true. When coding against the `SpecificStream` class, it doesn't make sense to check `canSeek()`, as its result is statically known, and it definitely doesn't make sense to call `seek()`. If such calls would be a programmer error, it makes sense to help the compiler give useful messages for such calls.

Answer (score 2):

It stops you from calling the method non-polymorphically, that's all: using the scope resolution operator to access a method directly can lead to difficult to maintain code. In an environment where you know that not everybody is an experienced implementer (scientific programmers contributing to a large codebase perhaps), it's worthwhile introducing patterns to protect your code from them!

That said, Java explicitly forbids it as they consider it bad style.

Comment: Then again, what does Java not forbid.